# A better idea/data structure to collect analytics data

Tags: data-structures, clojure

I'm collecting analytics data. I'm using a master map that holds many other nested maps.

Considering maps are immutable, many new maps are going to be allocated. (Yes, that is efficient in Clojure).
Basic operation that I'm using is update-in , very convenient to update a value for a given path or create the binding for a non-existant value.

Once I reached a specific point, I'm going to save that data structure to the data base.

What would be a better idea to collect these data more efficiently in Clojure? a transient data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all optimizations, **measure first**, and If the map update is a bottle neck then switching to a transient map is a rather unintrusive code change. If you find that GC overhead is the real culprit, as it often is with persistent data structures, and transients dont help enough then **collecting the data into a list and batch adding it into a transient map** which is made persistent and saved into the DB at the end may be a more effective though larger change. Adding to a list produces very little GC overhead because unlike adding to a map the old head does not need to be discarded and GCd